# Как изложить мысль ясно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

«По моему мнению, в течение 6−12 месяцев у России будет граница с Румынией. Если нет, тогда я скажу, что ошибся. Надеюсь, что так и произойдет, но не верю в это», — сказал Диаконеску.

Добравшись до последней буквы, я потерял связь с автором сообщения, и теперь "не верю" в написанное. Хармс назвал бы ЭТО оптическим обманом. Может достаточно убрать последнюю фразу?

Answer (score 3):

По-моему тут нужен психиатр, а не лингвист. Если за 6-12 месяцев диагноз не подтвердится, то я скажу, что ошибся.

Поскольку кое-кто воспринял всерьез, даю ссылку на первоисточник этой "гениальности". Я угадал в комментарии к ответу mueller. Признаюсь, что зная этого персонажа (экс-министра, не пользователя) по предыдущим откровениям, не испытывал затруднений.

http://news-times.ru/eks-glava-mid-diakonesku-cherez-polgoda-u-rf-budet-granica-s-rumyniej/

http://social.eadaily.com/blog/43742849087/Eks-glava-MID-Diakonesku:-CHerez-polgoda-u%A0Rossii-budet-granitsa

(9 июня, однако. Осталось 170 дней)

Answer (score 2):

Гениально путаная фраза. Сверх отмеченного, из неё нельзя понять ещё и то, какое развитие событий автор предполагает. То ли Россия прирастёт землями до румынской границы, то ли Румыния - до российской...  То ли на Днестре встретятся.
Если, однако, рассмотреть предложения строго последовательно - ясно, что он надеется ошибиться, но не верит, что ошибается. Общий смысл сказанного, в таком случае: адресованное России приглашение к торгу по украинским и молдавским территориям.

Comment: Главное, что граница не финско-корейская. Скорее всего автор имел в виду, что Приднестровье войдет в Россию, а Молдавия - в Румынию.

Answer (score 1):

Последняя фраза действительно сбивает читателя с толку. Становится неясно, на что надеется Диаконеску: на то, что через 6-12 месяцев у России будет граница с Румынией или на то, что он ошибся, и границы не будет. Если убрать последнюю фразу, главное в высказывании Диаконеску станет понятно: он предполагает, что через 6-12 месяцев у России с Румынией появится граница. Всё остальное в его высказывании - путанная передача его эмоций по поводу предполагаемого появления этой границы.

Comment: Креативно. Опять же не ясно, - сроки ставит под сомнение или перспективу общей границы с Россией.

Comment: Вероятно, он надеется на то, что ошибся и границы не будет, но одновременно не верит в то, что ошибся.

Comment: Он ставит под сомнение сроки, - ставить под сомнение сам факт появления (рано или поздно) границы между двумя суверенными государствами вменяемый политик не может.

Comment: С точки зрения формальных логических построений, это, может быть, выглядит так. Но мы не роботы, поэтому  "верить" и "не верить" для нас разные чувства.

Comment: Не верит в то, что ошибся, должно быть то же, что и верить в то, что не ошибся? Да он не так прост, этот Диаконеску.

Comment: Судя по его манере изложения своих мыслей, он не светоч разума. Но вполне может быть хитрым, непростым персонажем.

Comment: Прочитайте уже первоисточник, а??? По моей ссылке. Он не верит в ***то, что Россия нападет на Молдавию***. Шампар в своем фирменном стиле состыковал нестыкуемые куски текста.

Comment: В общем, в переводе на понятный язык Диаконеску сказал, что, по его мнению, в течение 6-12 месяцев РФ присоединит территорию Молдовы к своей территории. Если не присоединит, то он скажет, что ошибся. Он надеется, что НЕ присоединит, но надежда его слишком слаба.)